# Changing timeout limit when using conda install

Tags: anaconda

I originally posted this to the Continuum github but didn't get a response, so thought I'd try stackoverview.

I have been trying to create a Python 3.4 environment with the latest installer, which I managed to get through the early part fine. It downloads the first few packages but hangs at 99% then subsequently times out when it gets to this package.

https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/qt-5.6.2-vc14_3.tar.bz2

I can download it manually in Chrome but it has a similar behaviour - getting stuck at 55.2/55.3mb and stays there for a while before completing. I'm behind a proxy but I do have the correct proxy settings in .condarc. Is there a way to change the timeout limit when I'm downloading it through conda?

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue. In conda < 4.3.0, the timeout was hardcoded to 60 seconds. In Windows, I'm guessing, that's not enough for huge package with a lot of binary files like qt since most likely the virus scanner kicks in to check the files. You can hack your `~userid\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py` and change [the hard-coded constant](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/4.2.16/conda/fetch.py#L394) yourself, eg. from 60 to 300.

With newer version (I'm not sure when this was added, but I see this in my conda 4.3.22), running `conda config --show` gave: `remote_read_timeout_secs: 60.0`. So I believe you can modify it by adding it to your `~userid\.condarc` file.

Comment: You can also use `conda config --set remote_read_timeout_secs new_time_out` for temporarily use.